# scala spark sql with intellij, how to link jdbc jar file and run the scala code

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jdbc

I recently shifted my code from python to scala and created a project with scala environment including spark, i wrote a simple code to read the sql database table and add it as a dataframe and want to print the top 20 records with .show()

```
dataframe_mysql = sc.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_schema").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "testing").option("user", "root").option("password", "").load()
```

Iam unable to run the code and get the table records, previously in python i used to attach the jdbc driver as a argument while running the python on terminal so how do i implement the same in scala iam using intellij as my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SBT, you can import it to your project:

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.46" % "provided"
```

Eventually you can also manually include it with following steps:

1. Right Click on the project and Open Module Settings
2. Then go to Libraries and add it there the JAR.